# Ruby: reading a temporary zip file

Tags: ruby, zip, temporary-files

I have a `TempFile` object that is a zip file, and I wish to read from it as follows:

```
Zip::ZipFile.open_buffer(tempfile) do |zipfile|
    ...
end
```

However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Zip::ZipFile.open_buffer expects an argument of class String or IO. Found: Tempfile
```

I've also tried

```
Zip::ZipFile.open(tempfile.path) do |zipfile|
    ...
end
```

But that returns

```
can't dup NilClass
```

How can I process a temporary zip file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the temporary file was corrupted, so the

```
can't dup NilClass
```

error was as a result of trying to read the corrupted file.

Therefore the solution is to use

```
Zip::ZipFile.open(tempfile.path) do |zipfile|
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

See the following article http://info.michael-simons.eu/2008/01/21/using-rubyzip-to-create-zip-files-on-the-fly/ which explains how to use the more basic interface Zip::ZipOutputStream if you work with a Tempfile

Comment: Interesting- I'll bear that in mind if I need to write to a temp zip file. However, I have a different situation: I need to read zip entries from a temporary file created from a download.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error , but after digging i found out that these zip file should be in binary

i.e, first copy them to some file in binary mode then you can unzip it using ZIP module without facing the error

sample code

```
#copying zip file to a new file in binary mode

filename = "empty.zip" 
File.open(filename, "wb") do |empty_file|
  open("#{zipfile_url}", 'rb') do |read_file|
    empty_file.write(read_file.read)
  end
end

#now you can open the zip file

Zip::File.open(filename) do |f|
  . . .
end
```